# Is there a CSS trick to obtain a default font size on all devices

Tags: css, responsive-design

Is there any system independent way in CSS to obtain a standard-text font size from the browser, something that would be suitable for, say, a blog post?

I thought that em would do this, but when I set `font-size : 1 em;` I get a standard text font size on desktop and something extremely small on mobile.

I understand that sometimes the true DPI might be unknown to the OS. But on a mobile device, shouldn't the browser have some rough idea of how big readable text has to be? And shouldn't there be a way to obtain this information?

Comment: why don't you use media queries to adjust font size on mobile devices to your liking?

Comment: I would like to use a more generic approach.

Comment: There is no "more generic approach". Let's imagine you have the same resolution on a desktop browser and a mobile browser. The actual mobile browser size (the screen size) will be much smaller. So you have two options to make the font appear bigger on mobile devices: Either zoom in (e.g. by using a responsive design, adjusting the page's width) or by setting a bigger font size. Either way you will probably end up with media queries - that's just the way to go...

Comment: Let's assume that the browser has some idea of the screen: It knows the DPI and the screen dimensions. From that it should be able to estimate a text size that is comfortable to read while not taking up too much space. : A *default text size*, lets call it `1dts` . For a big screen that would maybe be 7mm while on mobile it would be 5mm. It would be extremely beneficial if it would be possible to have access to this size via css: `h1{ font-size: 3dts} div{font-size:1dts}` would then make sense on any device, without the need for a media-dependent switch.

Comment: Anyway, I get that this might not exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using em's then you first need to define a base value for the font. Ex.:

`body { font-size: 16px }`

Now 1em = 16px.

Most browsers have a default user-agent font-size of 16px but you shouldn't rely on it. Set the base value then start using em's.

Comment: 16 px is too small for mobile. I was hoping that it would be possible to ask the browser for a default size that looks good on whichever device the browser runs on. I am aware of the fact that the browser needs to make assumptions about screen DPI to be able to do this, but I would have guessed that this information is available on, say, android or iOS.

Comment: You may want to read this post: http://kdpeterson.net/blog/2011/06/font-size-in-mobile-browsers.html

Comment: That is a very interesting link. In that context, my question was if there is a way to ask the browser to return a font size that is "ideal" for the device that the browser runs on. I am aware that this would require the browser to have knowledge about the screen size and DPI. But I could imagine this to be possible on mobile OSs.

Comment: You might be able to programmatically with JavaScript, but with the only way I know with CSS in via media queries with device-pixel-ratio.

Comment: Ex.: @media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) { }

Answer (score 0):

If you want the standard system font size, you'd just do this in your CSS:

```
html {
    font-size: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

It's a best practice to define your font sizes in relative units (percentage, em) whenever possible so that they scale appropriately according to the target device's built-in settings.